# XSL Required: Merging content of next cell based on attribute of the current cell

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a Table it has two column.
Based on First column's rowmerge and rowspan attribute it should merge the values of next column.

RowMerged attribute is to find out whether cells are merged.
RowSpan attribute is to find-out how many cells are merged.
If Rowspan is 0 then that cells is merged with above one.

In the below example we give input as 5 Rows and it will return 3 row as output.
    ie) First two rows are merged into single and the content of second column which is not merged should be copied to the above one.

Concerned main on content of cell not the attribute.

## Sample Input:

```
<Table Name="abc">
    <TBODY>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="T" RowSpan="2"><Element>ABC</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>21</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="T" RowSpan="0"></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>ABC</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1"><Element>PQR</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>19</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="T" RowSpan="2"><Element>XYZ</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>99</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="T" RowSpan="0"></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>Sample</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
    </TBODY>
</Table>
```

## Sample Output:

```
<Table Name="abc">
    <TBODY>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1"><Element>ABC</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>21ABC</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1"><Element>PQR</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>19</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1"><Element>XYZ</Element></Cell>
            <Cell><Element>99Sample</Element></Cell>
        </Row>
    </TBODY>
</Table>
```

Comment: Attempted XSLT required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:variable name="rows" select="Cell[1]/@RowSpan"/>
        <xsl:copy>
                <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[1]/*" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Element>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Cell[2]/Element/node()" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Row[position() &lt; $rows]/Cell[2]/Element/node()" />
                </Element>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[Cell[1][@RowSpan > 0]]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TBODY">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[Cell[1][@RowSpan > 0]]" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With following output:

```
<Table Name="abc">
    <Row>
        <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1">
            <Element>ABC</Element>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
            <Element>21ABC</Element>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1">
            <Element>PQR</Element>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
            <Element>19</Element>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell RowMerged="F" RowSpan="1">
            <Element>XYZ</Element>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
            <Element>99Sample</Element>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer